# Dynamically Added Rows by jquery having issues

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form containing a select field id="projects" which upon being changed shows(using js) a hidden select field 'task' dynamically populating the tasks for the selected project by querying the dB. User can then enter hours which are updated on proj_id,task_id combination from the selects.

```
echo '<div id="dynform"><div class="rowhours"><select id="projects" name="project">';
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)
    echo '<option>No Projects assigned</option>';
else{
    echo '<option value="0">Project - Choose one</option>';
    while (list($proj_id, $title) = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
    {
        echo "<option value=$proj_id>$title</option>";   
    }
}

echo '</select></div><input type="button" id="add"></div>';
<select name="task" class="tasks" onchange="showOther(this, 'new');" onmouseover="showOther(this, 'new');"></select><br>

function showOther(fieldObj, otherFieldID)  //Function displays text box for creating a new task on Addhours.php 
            {                                       //for the selected project when "Enter New Task" option chosen
                var fieldValue = fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value;
                var otherFieldObj = document.getElementById(otherFieldID);

                otherFieldObj.style.visibility = (fieldValue=='other') ? '' : 'hidden';

                return;
            }
```

Now I added an 'Add Row' button, this generates the same form many times.

```
<input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add">

jquery used to add rows:  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('.rowhours').clone().appendTo('#dynform');
    });
});
```

Now when I change the projects of any row, the tasks select fields of all rows get affected, I know this is because they have the same Id's.

Question is how can I make them have different Id's and be able to use them seperately in the same manner using jquery. Also as of now I just update using the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) What can I use for the multiple rows now?

I have a working example here http://fracktal.in/tms/addhours.php

I am basically looking for having a project[] and task[] that I have no clue how to access using jquery or to get the posted values on form submit to update dB

Comment: could you share the code for showOther function

Answer (score 0):

Once you add `rowhours` access the last element and change the id

```
$(".rowhours).last().attr("id","newId");
```

Comment: You're missing a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

you can use arrays easily, just name your fields project[] (not project) and then access them with $_POST['project'][0], $_POST['project'][1], etc.

```
$total = count($_POST['project']);

foreach($_POST['project'] as $num=>$project) {
  // do your code here, send to DB or whatever
  // $project contains value of input (or select) and $num contains number of row
}
```